# Odoo PyCharm debug can't find my breakpoints

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-16

I Try to debug my Odoo module, but can't find out my breakpoints in result.
**IDE: PyCharm
OS:Ubuntu**

Also set debug setting in my **init**.py file

```
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('<HOST_IP>', port=5234, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

[image]

[image]

**I need to find my breakpoint in my module code:**
[image]
[image]
This part of code show Map Price on product page:
[image]

**But I can't find any data about my breakpoints**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your code in **init** file up. Like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('192.168.178.27', port=5234, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)

from . import models
from . import controllers
```